# How to go back multiple times in Firefox/Chrome without actually loading the previous site?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, history

Let's say I visited pages A,B,C and D. Is there any way to go back from D to say A without actually loading B and C and not using history menu?

This is a problem in cases when one site automatically redirects to another and it's impossible to go from C to B since C redirects to D. In Firefox, up to version 4, there was a list of recently visited sited near the back button, so it was easy to select which one I want, but this is now only accessible from history menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hold down or right-click the "back" button. It keeps a recent history.

#### Firefox 6:

[image]

#### Chrome 15:

[image]

Comment: This can also be done by right-clicking on the back button, for the non-Apple users. ;D